# Indoor position tracking using ble

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some ble beacons using which I need to determine and track the movement of android phones within the given area. I know there would have been a lot of research in this area already and would like to know what are the open source software which I can use to base my application on? Some pointers would help me.

I have a couple of beacons along with their range. Is there any open source algorithm which I can use to determine position?

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing you are talking is perhaps ranging and monitoring. There are no certain algorithms, you need to implement logic as per your requirement in your app. Please check this link. This would be really helpful

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

If you are going through BLE in NAdroid, check this

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html

Hope it hepls with your problem